# adding a drop arrow with css to a counter set number in a list

Tags: html, css

i have an OL list

```
<ol id="checkout-progress-state" class="checkout-progress">
<li class="active first" title="Select Addresses">
<span>Select Addresses</span>
<span class="notch"></span>
</li>
<li title="Shipping Information">
<span>Shipping Information</span>
</li>
</ol>
```

i have added the following css to the before state to create numbers that i can style

```
ol{counter-reset: progress-counter;font-size: 20px;}
ol li {border-top: 0 none white;position: relative;overflow: visible;display:inline-block; list-style-type: none;margin-right: 15px;} 
.checkout-progress li:before {
content: counter(progress-counter);
    counter-increment: progress-counter;
    }
    .checkout-progress li:before {border: 1px solid; border-radius: 12px;padding: 0 8px;margin-right: 10px;}
        .checkout-progress li.active:before {border: 1px solid #E96200; border-radius: 4px;padding: 0 6px;color: white; background-color: #E96200;}
 .notch {
    position: absolute;
    left: -10px;
    bottom: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid red;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 0;
    _border-right-color: pink;
    _border-left-color: pink;
    _filter: chroma(color=pink);
}
```

as you can see from this fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/euABv/ )the arrow is sitting to the left. i would like it to go below the orange box number. is there a way to do this with counter reset numbers?

this creates the numbers i want styled the way i want. BUT
I would like to add a notch to the bottom of the number box (active state).

i added notch info to the li and tried to position it but it wont display at the bottom of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Just add the `position:relative` in the outer class - `li.active first`

```
li.active first{
   position:relative;
}
```

Then, even you copy lots of the same element, the arrow will not change position.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/euABv/1/)

Comment: yeah um, li.active first is not a selector it would be li.active.first but anyway since the li is already positioned relatively this wouldnt be necessary.

Comment: by giving the bottom position a negative value i can get this to work. it just seems like not a great way to do it?